# Is there a way to disable hardware acceleration in one tab using google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas, hardware-acceleration

I am trying to prevent a webpage that is not under my control from creating a webgl context. It creates a canvas to do so. I know that disabling hardware acceleration will prevent it, but I do not want to be able to use hardware acceleration for HDR content on YouTube. Is there a way I can disable it on a page using JavaScript? If so, I may be able to create an extension. I have tried injecting an onload event handler using a chrome extension (which did not work). I was attempting to delete a canvas element as soon as it was created.

Is there any way to achieve this using chrome? Is there a way I could do this using an extension? Is it possible to prevent hardware acceleration from being used on a webpage using JavaScript?

If this is not a good question, please let me know and I will either edit it or remove it.

Comment: @amn It seems directly programming-related since they're trying to do it via programming.

Comment: @amn I was not sure where to put it as I am a dev and could implement my own solution. I am looking for either a software-based solution or a code-based solution.

Comment: I seriously doubt it since it's a browser-level control. You might be able to pre-load some JS that would disallow a *particular* page's JS, or parts of it (e.g., by stubbing/replacing) some user-space JS, but it might make more sense to look at something like GreaseMonkey (or whatever it is these days) instead of going full-extension route.

Comment: @DaveNewton I completely forgot about GreaseMonkey. I haven't used that in years. I will give that a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no way to disable hardware acceleration on a tab basis. The javascript route did not prove to be fruitful as it does not appear that you can trick a page into thinking that hardware acceleration is disabled (at least at page load where most pages would check).